# Java - ArrayList and creating an object

Tags: java, arraylist

The header question is a little bit tricky, so here's my problem:

1- I created an object y of an arraylist and I assigned it as a reference variable, so far so good.

```
ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2- Here I added an element to the array:

```
y.add("Hello"); y.add("GoodBye");
```

Now here's the part that I don't understand, now when I create a method that returns a String:

```
public String stringful(ArrayList<String> list)
```

Now when I try to get the size() of the array, I use list.size() but why? Isn't y the original object and I should use y.size() although it doesn't work so that's why I'm here. Thanks

Comment: You are using a method. That is why. List replaces what ever you pass to your method at a given moment. To become `local`.

Comment: Hint: What would happen if I write `stringful(z)`?

Comment: Since y is a variable that is local, my guess is that z will be passed into list and java will consider it a local variable without us having to declare it like what we did with y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this method header:

```
public String stringful(ArrayList<String> list)
```

You're declaring that this method will use an object, of type `ArrayList<String>` called `list`. Because you declare `y` locally, the other method has no idea that even exists. Reference to `y` from that method won't compile, assuming of course that it is a local variable.

**Pointers in Java**

When you create a new object, you use a pointer to that object. For example, when you declare:

```
ArrayList<String> y;
```

you're creating a pointer. When you add the code:

```
ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This puts the pointer to a new `ArrayList<String>` object into the `y` variable. So when you pass `y` as a parameter into a method, you're passing a pointer to the object that `y` also points to, not the object iself. This is why your code works with `list.size()`. All it's doing is getting the `size` value of the exact same object, just with a different pointer.

**Summary**

In Summary, it actually *is* the same object. It's just different pointers, looking at that object.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the reference to the `ArrayList<String> y` to method `stringful` to `list` reference variable  and hence will use `list.size()`. `y` is unknown to that method unless `y` is an instance or class variable which is visible in that method. `list` is the local variable  here which is used to pass the reference of `y`. This way you can pass a reference of any `ArrayList<String>` to that method and calculate its length. If you had used `y.size()` in that method (provided `y` is visible in that method), then you could have been able to calculate only the length of `ArrayList<String>` referenced by `y`.

Answer (score 2):

`y` is a **local variable**.
It only exists inside the function you declared it in.
`y` refers to an `ArrayList` instance.

When you write `stringful(y)`, you pass this `ArrayList` instance as a **parameter** to the function.
Within the function, you can refer to the value of the parameter using the `list` "variable" (it's actually a parameter, but it looks like a variable), which refers to the same instance you passed when you called it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). It goes through scoping and seems to be fairly clear.
For a quick example:

```
public class Test{
    private List<String> globalY;//accessable to anything in the class

    public Test(){
        globalY=new ArrayList<String>();
        globalY.add("global");   
    }

    //here, methodParam is only accessible inside this method
    public void example(ArrayList<String> method){
        //this list is only available inside this method
        List<String> local=new ArrayList<String>();
        local.add("local");

        System.out.println(globalY(0));
        System.out.println(method(0));
        System.out.println(local.get(0));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test=new Test();
        List<String> localY=new ArrayList<String>();
        localY.add("method");

        test.example(localY);
    }
}
```